# Qual ou quais as vantagens de se usar AWS-StepFunctions?

Tags: expressões-lambda, amazon-aws

Dado que ja existe um sistema ou processos em andamento (todos funcionais) com AWS - Lambda functions quais seriam as vantagens ou as desvantagens de se trazer esses processos para step functions, levando em consideração a curva de aprendizado e que ja temos os logs implementados em CloudWatch?

Em um outro cenário, e se estivéssemos iniciando o sistema do início?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o AWS Step Functions é usado para coordenar a execução de diversas funções em um fluxo de negócio, não em substituição. Ele oferece uma linguagem descritiva e visual para coordenar o sequenciamento e paralelismo das funções, para que você não precise fazê-lo em seu próprio código.